# How to modify original .net framework error page?

Tags: asp.net, exception, custom-error-pages

I want to change error page for all my websites on IIS.

How can I modify original .net framework error page for all of them at once?

[image: Error Page]

Comment: In the scope of the application or system wide?

Comment: @Serv Good Question, but I think all, i.e. "page for all of them at once"

Comment: I have 200 website on my IIS, I want to save time, I don't want to change all of their web.configs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have 200 website on my IIS, I want to save time, I don't want to change all of their web.configs..

Comment: You may be able to use powershell.  Microsoft generally make everything "adminable" using that.  See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f569096f-4036-4a52-85d3-8609e160716e/how-can-i-get-a-powershell-script-for-iis-to-set-custom-404-page-for-multiple-sites?forum=winserverpowershell .  The long and the short is the use of "{ Set-WebConfigurationProperty "

Comment: Can I change machine.config?

Comment: I doubt it.  Using the provided link you can run through the IIS folder and effect each individually.  With the provided code, it should not take more than a few seconds to run.